# Pandas Dataframe, Lambda not spitting out expected result?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm currently using pandas for some ETL and i am running into a weird issue with 1 line of code:

```
df_new['Location2'] = df_new['Type'].apply(lambda x: x if df_new.Location2.empty else df_new.Location2)
```

Instead of making Location2 = to Type when location2 is empty it simply sets it to = location 2 in a way that is weird. Sample Data with error:

[Sample CSV Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xG8E.png)

Comment: Could you add a piece of sample data into your question instead of the screenshot please?

Comment: @miradulo http://www.sharecsv.com/s/573e40787d22cb86abc864af4005717b/test11th.csv

Comment: Try and reduce the problem down to something you can demonstrate with a small dummy DataFrame. This will make your question more valuable for future viewers and easier for answerers to understand.

Comment: [Series.empty](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.empty.html) tests if the entire Series is empty. If that is not your intent, then please post the desired result.

Comment: @unutbu the desired result is to check if a specific row is empty or not. If it is take data from a different column

Comment: @scarecrow My guess is you want `df.Location.fillna(df.Type)`, but you should really work on improving your question.